# When $y = x^3 - 3x^2 - 24x - 7$, why is $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2 - 6x - 24$?

Tags: calculus

Pretty stupid/basic question, but I'm pretty poor at mathematics.

> $$
> y = x^3 - 3x^2 - 24x - 7\\
> \therefore \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 3x^2 - 6x - 24$$

I do not understand what the guy has done on the second line?  Could someone explain to me how he got the second line from the first?  : ) Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to try to use MathJax next time when posting such math problem.

Comment: he has differentiated the individual terms

Answer (score 6):

Notice that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions and $g(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, then

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(x) + g(x)] = \dfrac{df(x)}{dx} + \dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

Treating those terms like functions (and also, noting that the above expression holds for any number of functions), it's not hard to see that by power rule $\dfrac{d}{dx}[x^n] = nx^{n - 1}$ for any number $n$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
y &= x^3 - 3x^2 - 24x^1 - 7x^0\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= 3x^{3 - 1} - 3 \cdot 2x^{2 - 1} - 24 \cdot 1x^{1 - 1} - 7 \cdot 0x^{0 - 1}\\
&= 3x^2 - 6x - 24x^0 + 0\\
&= 3x^2 - 6x - 24
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks. But, it is hard to see if you do not know the rule.

Comment: @user118964 Are you familiar with derivatives at all?  The power rule is usually the first derivative formula that gets taught after the derivative is introduced...

Comment: Not knowing the source of his confusion, you might want to add that the derivative of a sum is the sum of derviatives.

Comment: "Thanks. But, it is hard to see if you do not know the rule".  Then read a Calculus text!  It is hard to do anything if you "do not know the rules".